# Doubletap event on input text on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following event which fires after the user double clicks inside an `text input` element. It works fine in desktop browsers but nothing happens on mobile ones. I have tried other events like `doubletap` but nothing happens. It's the keyboard only that shows. A `long tap` also will be fine.

```
<input type="text" id="search">

$(document).on('dblclick', '#search', function() {
    //
});
```

**The solutions in the other question doesn't work on text input.**

Comment: Check this : https://forum.jquery.com/topic/doubletap-event

Comment: This doesn't work on `text input` @Gothdo